# Can you isolate audio data given two mics?

Tags: algorithm

So I had an idea for a program, but I really have no idea if it would work, and I didn't really know where to post this question. I used [which computer science programming stack exchange sites do I post on](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/129598/which-computer-science-programming-stack-exchange-sites-do-i-post-on) in order to determine, that since this is an algorithmic question (can this algorithm be written), I thought this would be the best place.

So the idea is this. Imagine you are sitting at a table with someone else each of you have a mic, as if you're doing a podcast or something. Your voice is being heard by your mic, and the other mic, albeit faintly.

The question is, can you use the distance between the two mics to act as a filter on your voice only?

Your voice is heard by the mic in front of you first, then by the mic further away from you at a very specific interval, since they are stationary. Any audio elsewhere in the room reaches the two mics at different interval signatures, for instance, if at a perpendicular angle the audio would reach the two mics at the same time.

It seems to me that this relationship could be used to isolate audio coming from a certain angle and filter out all the rest. Is this possible? Is it done already?

[image: sketch]

Comment: I believe this would fall within the research area of "Audio Source Separation". https://www.researchgate.net/publication/290857383_Separating_musical_audio_signals works with a setup somewhat reminiscent of your description.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because as currently worded, it's a purely hypothetical question that has nothing to do with programming.

Comment: @pjs perhaps you're right, it has nothing to do with implementation if that's how you define programming. It is a purely algorithmic question, abstracted away from any specific implementation. But we don't seem to have a place for pure abstract logic, do we? Where would this go? some Math exchange? Physics exchange? doesn't seem right, does it? because we're talking about creating a filter, logic, a map, a program, a function: code. Perhaps it doesn't belong here. But where does abstract logic belong then?

Comment: Not my job to tell you where to place it, I'm just pointing out that it doesn't fit the guidance for SO.  https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic.

Comment: @pjs https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/129598/which-computer-science-programming-stack-exchange-sites-do-i-post-on this place seems like the best option.

Comment: Are you asking for a recommendation for an algorithm?  Doing so is explicitly off-topic.  If not, what specific algorithm are you having problems with?  "Can you...?" "It seems to me... Is this possible?" - you're posing a hypothetical/opinion-based question.  These are all flags for being off-topic.  I've voiced my opinion via a vote, if others agree or disagree so be it.

Comment: I think I've described the algorithm in sufficient detail, I'm not asking for a recommendation, I'm asking if there's something I've overlooked that makes the algorithm fail to produce the results I've suggested it could. To recap, the algorithm is: 1. obtain the distance between the two mics (any way you like) 2. Any similar noise signature that takes about that amount of time to show in the data stream between the two mics keep, 3. else disregard. Question: would this function serve to isolate the noise of one or two speakers in a crowded room? Have I overlooked something? does the func run?

Comment: Frankly, now that I think about it, you could even isolate noise by distance by comparing the volume between the two mics. If you're far away the volume will be negligible, if you're the speaker in front of the mic, the volume difference would large. so you could pinpoint a sphere in space and say any nose that comes from this sphere, keep, else filter out. That is pretty cool.